# Curl command that do a weird call in jenkins-pipeline

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to call a service that is located on one of my server with a curl command like this :

```
sh "curl -v -u User:password http://${host}:00000/invoke/link/someService"
```

As you can see it the name of my server is in a var call ${host} that I defined at the start of the Jenkinsfile like this `def host` and that I get from a file later in the job.

My issue is that when I run the curl command it didn't run it completely, in fact it does not take into account what is after the host name : [image]

As you can see above there isn't the port and the end of the link. I another job I do a similar curl command and it work well, so I don't understand why it doesnt work

Regards,

Please forgive my approximate English

**EDIT :**

At the beginning of my script, just before the `node{}` I define my var like this :

```
def Host
```

Next, in the first stage I get my Host from a file on the workspace with a grep like this : `Host= sh(script: "grep $env ./conf/env.properties | cut -f2 -d\',\'", returnStdout: true)`

And finaly, in another stage I call the curl with the host that i retrieve in the first stage in my curl command like this :

sh "curl -v -u login:passhttp://${host}:00000/invoke/someService"

Comment: Can you give a minimal `Jenkinsfile` example? I am unable to reproduce. Maybe your build is taking a different `Jenkinsfile` than the one you are making changes to?

Comment: Hello, sorry I was sick so I don't answer quickly, I add information in the Edit part of the first message. Moreover, I am  sure that my job use the good jenkinsfile. Hopefully, the information that i added can provide some help !